# Can remove cookie in IE8 but not chrome13, firefox3.6

Tags: cookies, setcookie

Has cookie on browser, my domain is zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp

Cookie information:

name:Vanilla-Volatile

value:1-1313808454|54614728ee113ab09e4db5c863cd5cfa|1313635654|1|1313808454

domain:zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp

path:/

I send a request a request to zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp/ddd/j-security-logout, in fiddler i can see the response code is 302, and contains header:

Set-Cookie: Vanilla-Volatile=""; Domain=zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/

however, the cookie is not removed.

[8.26] 
Last time when I test, I can remove cookie in IE, but can not remove cookie in chrome and firefox. But today can remove in chrome but not in IE or firefox. so confuse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After try response.setContentType("text/html"). cookie can be remove in IE and chrome, but not firefox, but it's not the same problem. I have created another question [Fail to remove cookie in Firefox with Java; Firefox creates a new cookie with dot at the head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199438/fail-to-remove-cookie-in-firefox-with-java-firefox-create-a-new-cookie-with-dot)

Answer (score -1):

IE8 and its predecessors are garbage and don't actually delete cookies until the browser is restarted, even if you tell it to. Does the cookie exist after a browser restart? http://ebmgh.com/blog/2009/12/ie8-does-not-really-delete-cookies-until-restart/

Comment: I can not sure if it's the same issue.
As I have success remove another cookie in domain prod.xxxx.corp and path /vanilla