# Fail to remove cookie in Firefox with Java; Firefox creates a new cookie with dot at the head

Tags: java, firefox, cookies

I have this cookie in Firefox:

```
name:Vanilla-Volatile

value:1-1313808454|54614728ee113ab09e4db5c863cd5cfa|1313635654|1|1313808454

domain:zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp

path:/
```

Then, I try to reset the cookie in Java with this code:

```
  def c = new Cookie("Vanilla-Volatile", null);
  c.setDomain("zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp");
  c.setPath('/');       
  response.addCookie(c);
```

Instead of resetting the cookie,  Firefox creates a new cookie with `domain=.zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp` (notice the '.' at the head.)

Is there a workaround for this issue?

I'm using Firefox version 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
c.setDomain("zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp");
```

A cookie can either be set for a single host (the default) or for a whole domain. Apparently, you want to set it for a single host ("zhu13890.prod.xxxx.corp", the host where this script runs). So you should not specify a domain.